# how do i write output to file even if variable does not exist

Tags: powershell, active-directory

@AdminOfThings, thanks for your reply but didn't not work and seemed to complicate troubleshooting for me. here is what i have now and outputs to the shell correctly but leaves blanks where the catch block should be writing when exported to csv. any ideas?

```
Function Get-LegalHolds {

$users = get-content C:\temp\users.txt

foreach ($user in $users){
Try
{
 Get-ADUser $user -Properties * | Select-Object CN,cvx-LegalSubjectToHold
}
Catch
{
 Write-Output "$user does not exist"
}
}
}

Get-LegalHolds
```

Comment: I see what you are doing more in your deleted post. The deleted answer helps more than the original question. Since you are using a function to retrieve the user information, in your `catch` block you will need to output a custom object. Those properties need to match what the successful queries produce. Does that make sense? If we say a user has properties `a`,`b`,`c` and you output that to a CSV, you will see a row of data with values that line up under the `a`,`b`,`c` columns. If you find no objects and just output `user does not exist`, there are no `a`,`b`,`c` properties. You need them.

Comment: The most important question is what do you want to see in the CSV file when you don't find the user?

Comment: makes perfect sense! how would i go about doing that? sorry my post is such a mess LOLOL

Comment: all i would actually need is the $user

Comment: What is the format of `$user`? Is it a `SamAccountName`?

Comment: You are only wanting two columns, `CN`,`cvx-LegalSubjectToHold`, when you find a user. That means you will need to use one of those columns for your failure output. You could just do `$user | select @{n='CN';e={$_}},cvx-LegalSubjectToHold` in your `catch` block. `CN` would have `$user` in it and the other property would be blank.

Comment: yes
isn't that the issue? there is no SamAccountName for some  ($user in $users)

Comment: You could just add `SamAccountName` to your `try`. Then use that in your `catch` too.

Comment: Not outputting objects with the same properties is your problem. You just need to do that. `Select-Object CN,cvx-LegalSubjectToHold` outputs two properties regardless of how much data `Get-ADUser` returns. `"$user does not exist"` outputs a string with one property, which is `Length`. You need a custom output for `catch` that has the same properties as the `try` output. `Select-Object` or `Select` is the way to do it. I personally think the two properties is not enough to clearly output your findings in the same CSV.

Comment: thanks for the help. you got me mostly where I needed to be. i went ahead and accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for what `cvx-LegalSubjectToHold` is, but in general the following principles should apply.

I would change the code to be something like the following:

```
Function Get-LegalHolds {

    $users = Get-Content C:\temp\users.txt

    foreach ($user in $users){
        Try
        {
            Get-ADUser $user -Properties CN,cvx-LegalSubjectToHold |
                Select-Object SamAccountName,CN,cvx-LegalSubjectToHold
        }
        Catch
        {
            $user | Select-Object @{n='SamAccountName';e={$_}},CN,cvx-LegalSubjectToHold
        }
    }
}

Get-LegalHolds
```

To address exporting nonusers, you will need to output an object with named properties that match the properties output by the found users. Objects with mismatched properties cause issues with CSV exports. You may need to adjust the properties in the `Select` commands to your liking.

I changed `-Properties` to explicitly list the properties beyond the default set that you want to return. Using `*` will output everything and is not best practice and consumes unnecessary system resources.